# Apple push notifications - firewall?

Tags: iphone, firewall, push, wifi

I've read that to receive push notifications over Wifi the firewall must allow TCP traffic over port 5223. However, the network administrator tells me he needs the IP addres of the server. Would it be gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com?

Thanks!

Comment: The apple documenation:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html

doesn't seem to mention what ip is used for inbound traffic.

gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com may work, but in the documentation it only mentions it as the point in which you send messages from your service to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Technical Note: [TN2265](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-SUBSECTION14)

Comment: Thank you, I solved the issue some other way, but this certainly answers my question!

Comment: @fede What is the "other way"?